# JPA persistence.xml - add DAO from referenced library

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

My question is quite simple.
Is it possible to add a DAO from a referenced library?
Fx. if you have multiple micro-services running sharing a some DAOs.

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>

    <class>someproject.models.awesomeDAO</class>
    <class>referencedLibrary.models.sharedDAO</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by DAOs you actually mean Entities. You can add any entity class explictly with the `<class>` tag in persistence.xml as long as they are in the classpath.

You can even reference a jar file to be searched for annotated classes so you don't need to declare them explicitly with the tag `<jar-file>`

Comment: If I'm using SBT for my project, would I have to manually add it to my classpath, or is setting up the dependency enough?

libraryDependencies += "someproject" % "commonLib" % "1.0"

Comment: Haven't used SBT, but if it is similar to maven, adding a dependency would be enough